# Instaling MySQL using Puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm new in puppet. It's my first experience with it. I've installed a master and an agent on 2 Centos7 vm's. I've already installed Apache with puppet. It seems to work fine. Now I am trying to install MySQL, written my site.pp as

```
class { '::mysql::server' :
     root_password => 'password',
     }
```

but I facing an issue

```
 Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Unknown function mysql::deepmerge at /etc/puppet/modules/mysql/manifests/server.pp:117
```

please help me in fixing this error.

Comment: That error message suggests that the mysql module you're trying to use (which is not itself part of Puppet proper) is not compatible with the version of Puppet you have installed on the server.  Not enough information has been provided to say much else.

Comment: Thanks Johan but I am using puppet 3.8.7 which is the latest one and MySQL moudule puppetlabs-mysql (v7.0.0) on Centos-7.

Comment: Not only is Puppet 3.8 not the latest, it is not even supported any longer.  The latest is [Puppet 6.0](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/puppet_index.html), though that's still pretty fresh -- I'm personally sticking with Puppet 5.5 for the time being.  Version 7.0.0 of [puppetlabs-mysql](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/mysql) requires at least Puppet 4.7.